I can't detect a new version of my package in VS 2022 Package manager
I am currently experiencing an issue while creating a .nupkg file and trying to install it manually. My method involves placing the package.nupkg file in a specific folder located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\myPack\1.0.0\.
However, despite my efforts, I am unable to successfully install the package. I've noticed that other versioned folders (for example: 1.0.0/, 1.0.1/, etc.) contain more than just the .nupkg file. I'm wondering whether the lack of other files may be causing the issue.
In these other folders, I have noticed presence of:

A .NUSPEC file
Metadata file
.nupkg.sh512 file
And the .nupkg file itself

For installation, I have attempted to use the Package Manager console, but without success.
Despite following several relevant tutorials carefully, I am not able to accomplish the installation the way I anticipated.
Could these additional files be the problem? If not, what am I missing or what could be the reason why I can't install the package from this location?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
